# How to run procedure from package in one-time Oracle job?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, jobs

I am trying to make procedure that can create multiple jobs. That jobs will execute procedures from different packages. For example:

Some package:

```
declare
 executed_text   varchar2;
begin
   --specifying what procedure would be executed in jobs

   executed_text:='Z$RA_MTHREADS_DUMMY.DUMMY_PIPE(3);'

   -- calling main procedure, that makes jobs

   Z$RA_MTHREADS.RA_MULTI_T.CREATEJOB(
         executed_text,  -- what to run in jobs
         3,              -- number of jobs
         'some_package'  -- name of jobs
   );
end;
```

Main procedure, that makes jobs

```
procedure CREATEJOB(task_string IN varchar2,
                    job_cnt IN number,
                    job_name IN varchar2) is
begin
     for jobnum in 1..job_cnt loop
          -- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
             -- and here I have to create one-time job, that starts
             -- passed in task_string procedure
          -- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
     end loop;
end;
```

I've tried to do this with dbms_scheduler.create_job, but it just doesn't create

```
dbms_scheduler.create_job 
(  
  job_name      =>  job_name||jobnum,  
  job_type      =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',  
  job_action    =>  'begin '||task_string||' end;',  
  start_date    =>  SYSTIMESTAMP,  
  enabled       =>  TRUE,  
  auto_drop     =>  TRUE,  
  comments      =>  'one-time job');
```

Comment: There are no errors, on submission or on execution? Does your `job_name` include the package schema?

Comment: The text string with the procedure name to be executed should include the schema. I don't know if what you've got there is a schema name or is the name of a package. Share and enjoy.

Comment: You are right, I forgot schema name in `executed_text` from the first example. Stupid mistake >_<